# How to convert a base-26 string to an integer?

Tags: c++

I have a string "D", that I want to convert into the integer 4.

*(Additional information from OP)*

D should convert into a decimal value . I want it to be "4".

for D = "4" ; E = "5"; and so on...

It may have the combination . If AA comes ,the value should be 27 and ll increase consequetively.

Comment: What should "D" convert to? Hexadecimal?

Comment: It sounds really odd... Please provide more info about your task.

Comment: D should convert into a decimal value . I want it to be "4".

Comment: for  D = "4" ; E = "5";and so on...

Comment: Always a single character, or might you have "AZG" to convert?

Comment: It may have the combination . If AA comes ,the value should be 27 and ll increase consequetively.

Comment: Ok. Finally, what programming language? visual studio and qt4 don't seem to have anything to do with this..

Comment: Ok, I fixed your tags. I'm not fluent in c++, but someone who is might see this Q now. In the mean time, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal for a hint - there's some java code, `fromBase26` function - that's what you want to do.

Comment: joki, can the string contain more than one letter?  How long can the string be?  (Regular ints can not store very large numbers.)

Comment: How is `0` represented in what you are calling "base-26"? Or how about decimal `26`? Seems your numbering system is broken...

Comment: Are you trying to hash? in other words: should the resulting number be unique for every string or two strings can have the same result?

Comment: **Please edit your question**. Your question is so vague and this comment stream is getting too long. Incorporate more detail into the answer instead of tacking everything on in comments. Also [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Also 2 people asked you questions and you did not answer.

Comment: Haven't got a clear answer . And so asked again in a brief manner.

Comment: Please do not do that! If you're not getting the answer you require it's because you haven't provided enough detail. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and then update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is what you want (based on your question and comments):

```
unsigned long long convert(string str)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<str.length();i++)
        result+= (str[i] - 'A' + 1) + i*26;
    return result;
}
```

Now for `"D"` it will give `4`, for `"AA"` it will give `1+26 = 27` and so on...

Comment: "AA" gives 28 not 27

Comment: Assuming this solution is meant to convert a [bijective base-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system) number into decimal, it gives incorrect results:
"A" → 1 ✔️
"B" → 2 ✔️
"Z" → 26 ✔️
"AA" → 28 ❌27
"AB" → 29 ❌28
"BA" → 53 ❌29
"ZA" → 53 ❌677
"ZZ" → 78 ❌702
"AAA" → 28 ❌703

Answer (score 1):

A one-character string isn't so hard:

```
const int fromBase26 = ('D' - 'A') + 1;
```

This will set `fromBase26` to 4.

For n-digit base parsing the algorithm is something like:

```
set output to 0
while input digits to convert:
  output *= base
  output += least significant input digit
  remove least significant input digit from input
```

Note that this reads digits from the right of the input.

Comment: This is a pretty narrow interpretation of the original question. Why not just respond with `const int fromBase26 = 4;`?

Comment: Am not clear with this . can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
char* str = "ABC";
int i, len, num, pos;


len = strlen(str);
num = 0;
pos = 1;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    num += pos * ((str[i] - 'A') + 1);
    pos *= 26;
}
```

`num` will contain the result.

Comment: So, what is the result of converting "A"?